# sdelete.exe is not working with cfexecute

Tags: coldfusion, user-accounts, coldfusion-8, cfexecute

I am trying to run sdelete.exe (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx) using cfexecute, but I think cfexecute is not even running that command.

It's not giving me any permission error. And I have given all admin privileges to ColdFusion service -> logon tab.

The following is the line that I have in my .cfm page that run successfully but doesn't delete the file:

```
<Cfexecute name="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\sdelete.exe" arguments="-p 2 C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Deepak\testP\removeme.txt" outputfile="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Deepak\testP\out.txt"></Cfexecute>
```

I am able to execute it in command prompt writing:

```
>C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\sdelete.exe -p 2 C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Deepak\testP\removeme.txt
```

And remove.txt is gone!

I have checked all the windows and ColdFusion logs, and didn't found anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sdelete starts up for the first time, it gives a GUI prompt for you to accept the license agreement.

ColdFusion is a server process, which would usually run under a different user account. So you need to run sdelete on that account and accept the agreement. To do so, you can use the Run As command.

Comment: Yes I already did accept agreement, And after that it works in command prompt too, but not working with cfexecute!!

Comment: Maybe ColdFusion is running as a different user.

Comment: I am able to cfexecute ping command, and Coldfusion runs under webadmin account, which I guess has all permissions.

Comment: Do not guess ;) Log in under the *same account* CF is using. Run sdelete.exe from a command prompt. What are the results?

Comment: You might also be able to use the "Run as" command instead of logging in.

Comment: Thanks Leigh and Nayuki. @Leigh: right I should never guess :) ,@Nayuki: I run it as webadmin and have to click 'Agree' before using cfexecute

Comment: @Deepak - You mean you are prompted *every* time? From what I have read, there is no flag to disable the agreement prompt. The suggestion is trying a registry hack http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic10083&OB=DESC.html or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/70b2419e-cb1a-4678-b2ae-cedcfe08d06f

Comment: Nono, you are prompted only once per Windows user account. The problem was that the web server process was running under a different account.

Comment: Lol. Yes, that is what I *expected* to happen. But his last response made it sound like that was *not* what actually *did* happen ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add a timeout value to `cfexecute`

ie `timeout="100"`